# Does unit operator and parity have equal number of linearly independent eigenfunctions?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory, mathematical-physics, eigenfunctions

Unit operator commutes with the parity operator i.e., $[\mathbb{1},\mathbb{P}]=0$. Any function $f(x)$ is an eigenfunction of the unit operator $\mathbb{1}$ while only even or odd functions are eigenfunctions of parity operator $\mathbb{P}$. I define unit operator as $\mathbb{1}f(x)=f(x)$. A parity operator is defined as $\mathbb{P}^2=\mathbb{1}$ or $\mathbb{P}f(x)=f(-x)$. Let the vector space be $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. Both $\mathbb{P}$ and $\mathbb{1}$ are hermitian in this space.

**EDIT:** In this space, do both operators have an equal number of linearly independent eigenfunctions? How do we prove that?

Comment: I have a few questions. What is the parity operator? What is the unit operator? What makes you think that “Since they commute, they have a complete set of common eigenfunctions”?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I define unit operator as $\mathbb{1}f(x)=f(x)$. A parity operator is defined as $\mathbb{P}^2=\mathbb{1}$ or $\mathbb{P}f(x)=f(-x)$. If two Hermitian operators commute, they'll have a complete set of common eigenfunctions. It's a theorem.

Comment: I forgot one question: what's the space you're working with?

Comment: space of real functions

Comment: You mentioned Hermitian operators. That makes sense only in an inner product space. Which inner product do you habe in mind?

Comment: $L^2(\mathbb{R})$...inner products as defined in quantum mechanics $(f_1,f_2)=\int f_1^*f_2 dx$.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to invoke a theorem in order to prove that if an operator commutes with the identity operator, then they have common eigenvectors. That's trivial, since *any* (non-zero) vector is an eigenvector of the identity operator and *any* operator commutes with the identity operator.

So, the answer to your question is “yes”, but it's quite trivial. Indeed, there are infinitely many eigenvectors of the parity operator and each of them is an eigenvector of the identity operator. So, both operators have infinitely many eigenvectors.

Comment: My question is whether unit operator and parity have an *equal number of linearly independent eigenvectors*.

Comment: Please see the edited version of my answer.

Comment: Infinitely many *linearly independent* eigenvectors? Is there a way to compare the number of linearly independent eigenvectors of the unit operator and of parity?

Comment: Of course. $\exp(-x^2),x^2\exp(-x^2),x^4\exp(-x^2),\ldots$ are all eigenvectors of both operators (with eigenvalue $1$) and they are linearly independent. Don't you agree?

Comment: Yes. I do. What about $\exp(-x)$? It's an eigenvector of unit op. but not that of parity.

Comment: That's because your “theorem” is false. Congratulations. You found a counter-example.

Comment: When [A,B]=0, the theorem doesn't say every eigenvector A must also be an eigenvector of B or vice-versa. It says there is an overlap of common eigenfunctions.

Comment: If they have a common eigenvector, then the eigenvectors overlap. That's sort of trivial, right?

Comment: Edited the question slightly. You might want to have a look. @JoséCarlosSantos